# JavaFX: Change a TextField or Text object in a controller class while maintaining the separation of view and controller

Tags: java, oop, javafx, controller, event-handling

I'm struggling to find a way to alter the TextField and Text objects of the view class from the controller class without just passing the TextField and Texts to the controller and then altering them using commands such as textField.setText() which I know is in breach of the whole separation idea. I am creating a game to guess a number between 1 and 50.

Example:

View Class:

This class will set up the stage with Labels, Texts, and TextFields for user input, as well as buttons. There is a button to guess if the number you entered into the TextField is correct. When the guess button is clicked I call for the setOnAction method in the view class which then calls a method from the controller class to handle the events. I realise that I cannot just pass in the TextField to the Controller because you need to keep the view separate from the controller so I can pass in the TextField.getText() and Text.getText() as shown bellow in order to convert it to a string first which keeps them separate. In this example enteredNumber is a TextField and result is a Text.

```
guessButton.setOnAction(e -> guessingGameController.guessButtonAction(enteredNumber.getText(), result.getText()));
```

I then read and process the data in the controller class:

```
public void guessButtonAction(String enteredNumber, String result) {

        int enteredValue = Integer.parseInt(enteredNumber);

            if (enteredValue == randomNum) {
                result = ("YOU WON!!!");
            } 
            else if (enteredValue != randomNum) {
                result = ("Unlucky the number was " + randomNum);
        }
    }
```

I realise that I can simply return the String result from the controller and then have the view class make the Text resultBox set the text like this:

```
 guessButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String result = guessButtonAction( 
                      enteredNumber.getText(), result.getText());
                resultBox.setTex(result);
            }
        });
```

But There are a few buttons that would have to return more then one variables meaning I'd have to return an array which I feel complicates things too much. Is there any other way of doing this without being so messy and maintaining the separation of the GUI and the processing of data? I apologise for the long question, I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: The controller is **meant** to *control* the UI elements, so calling `textField.setText()` from within the controller is absolutely appropriate... I think that much of what you believe about the MVC pattern (in particular how it relates to JavaFX) may be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting because my lecturer told me to avoid passing any and all UI elements to the controller class at all costs. Thank you for the reply though. @Zephyr

Comment: Interesting indeed. The MVC pattern in JavaFX generally consists of: **Model** (data classes), **View** (FXML layout files), **Controller** (the code that controls the view).  You could read more in the MVC section of the [JavaFX Best Practices](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm) from the offiicial JavaFX documentation. There are many other resources available that would advise against whatever your instructor is telling you to attempt.

Comment: Well appreciated, we are currently not using any FXML but I'm sure I should still follow the same guidelines. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, there may be exceptions when coding the view in Java instead of FXML; that just is not necessarily the way JavaFX was designed and your instructor's approach is going to lead to many complications, as you are already seeing.

Comment: I agree, I'll ask him about all this tomorrow anyway.